# Jmeter using newly defined variable in User Defined Variables

Tags: jmeter

I want to define a variable in `User Defined Variables` and use it in the same config element later. I've tried for just defined `smoke` variable to add below it another line with  value:
${__javaScript(${smoke} > 0 ? 10 : 100)}
${__if(${smoke},1,0,2,)}

1st line gives ${smoke} not defined error in log, 2nd line produces 2 always (smoke == 1 or 0).

I know workaround of defining property, however, could my goal be achived by just variables and if yes, than how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) documentation:

> the variables are not available for use until after the element has been processed, so you cannot reference variables that are defined in the same element. You can reference variables defined in earlier UDVs or on the Test Plan.

and

> UDVs should not be used with functions that generate different results each time they are called. Only the result of the first function call will be saved in the variable

So if you really want to go this way make sure to define your `${smoke}` variable in another User Defined Variables

---

In general you don't even need to use the User Defined Variables, [__javaScript() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) has second argument which can be used for storing evaluation result in an arbitrary JMeter Variable:

[image]

---

[Since JMeter 3.1 users are encouraged to use scripting language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) which provides maximum performance, as of [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1) you should be using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) where possible.